# Firebase Cloud Function not returning response

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the following cloud function that will not return a value, even though we have an explicit response that is being logged right before the return statement:

```
export const startFormatInitialAtlistedData = functions
    .runWith(runtimeOpts)
    .region("us-central1")
    .https.onCall(async (data) => {
      functions.logger.log("THIS IS data startFormatInitialAtlistedData", data);
      return manageFormatInitialAtlistedData().then((locresp) => {
        functions.logger.log(
            "startFormatInitialAtlistedData: resp!!!!!",
            locresp
        );
        if (locresp.success) {
          functions.logger.log(
              "startFormatInitialAtlistedData: resp.success!!!!!",
              locresp.success
          );
          return ({success: true, fileName: "", exit: 18});
        } else {
          return ({success: false, fileName: "", exit: 19});
        }
      })
          .catch((err) => {
            functions.logger.log(
                "startFormatInitialAtlistedData error",
                err);
            return Promise.reject(err);
          });
    });
```

manageFormatInitialAtlistedData returns a response like Promise({success: true, fileName: "", exit: 14}), and from the following logs we can see that this is returned:

{"success":true,"fileName":"","exit":14,"severity":"INFO","message":"startFormatInitialAtlistedData: resp!!!!!"}

The next log statement confirms that we are getting right to the return statement:

{"severity":"INFO","message":"startFormatInitialAtlistedData: resp.success!!!!! true"}

The only weird thing that I see is that the first logged message is printed in the wrong order,
it should be like:

{"severity":"INFO","message":"startFormatInitialAtlistedData: resp!!!!!","success":true,"fileName":"","exit":14}

I am very curious as to why this is not working, as all of my other functions return the statement with no problems. Also of note: I have tried using return await manageFormatInitialAtlistedData() here with no effect on the output. I am very confused as to why my response is logged but not actually returned, which leaves the function to execute until it times out.

Comment: We have no means to check how the function `manageFormatInitialAtlistedData()` works. Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question and as stated by the answer below, it can be that you're not resolving the promise from the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are not resolving the `Promise` in your `manageFormatInitialAtlistedData` function maybe.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y9jp6ag2

```
function manageFormatInitialAtlistedData() {
    return Promise.resolve({success: true, fileName: "", exit: 14});
}

async function myFunc() {
    return manageFormatInitialAtlistedData().then((resp) => {
    if (resp.success) {
        return ({success: true, fileName: "", exit: 18});
    } else {
      return ({success: false, fileName: "", exit: 19});
    }
  });
}


(async () => {
  const ret = await myFunc()
  console.log(ret);
})();
```

This works when called.

Comment: I had manageFormatInitialAtlistedData() quitting and returning after either 8 mins (480000 ms) or when the last of the firestore documents are processed. I first tried processing fewer docs by starting the processing further towards the end, which gave me the desired response. I am now quitting after 60 seconds instead, and the correct response is returning to me. It is also worth noting that I have my runtime options (runtimeOpts) set to 540 seconds... Do you see any way I could run this function for at least those 8 mins?

Comment: @WillemGhijsen I don't exactly follow the question. And this seems like a new question to me. Maybe you could do that and add more details.